# How does Bootstrap darken the page background behind a modal

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I can't seem to figure out what Bootstrap is doing to darken the background of a page when a modal is shown. I see that a class is added to the body tag (modal-open) but that doesn't seem to affect the background.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

[image]

Comment: My bet would be a large semi-transparent black overlay.

Answer (score 3):

I used a diff tool to see the difference between the modal open and the modal closed html and found the answer. When the modal is shown, Bootstrap inserts an empty div just above the closing body tag:

`<div class="modal-backdrop fade show"></div>`

When the modal is closed, the div is removed. The `.modal-backdrop.show` class has an opacity value of 0.5.

So that's how it's done!